# How to escape blade instructions in a blade template?

Tags: laravel-blade

I'm writing a tutorial on Sass in a blade template and want to discuss Sass' @include syntax. But '@include' is a reserved command in Blade. How can I escape this?

Sample html in my blade template:

```
<p>Use <code>@include</code> to include a Sass <code>@mixin</code>...</p>
```

**Edit:**

I can escape the @ in HTML by using `&#64;`, but am still interested if there is a way to escape the Blade instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to solve this situation by writing  - `{{ '@'.'include' }}` instead of `@include` in your Blade template.
So your whole thing would look like:

```
<p>Use <code>{{ '@'.'include' }}</code> to include a Sass <code>@mixin</code>...</p>
```